# how to match items belonging to a particular category in Blogspot

Tags: ruby

In my code, I have a section that extracts and lists the different categories of posts but my problem is how to get exactly the posts that fall within that category and list them only. This is an example of my code:

```
category = Array.new
docs.elements.each("*/entry/category")  { |element|
category << element.attributes['term']}
title = Array.new
docs.elements.each("*/entry/title")  do |element|
title << element.text
end

category.each_with_index {|category, index|
puts "  For Catergory :    #{category}
The title is : #{title[index]} "
 puts '---------------------------------------------------'
```

The output of the above code is as follows and I would want to match like categories with their titles.

For Catergory :    A good Begining

The title is : Today

---

For Catergory :    Circular

The title is : Life

---

For Catergory :    Circular

The title is : Let Me try

---

For Catergory :    A good Begining

The title is : Check

---

For Catergory :    time shall time

The title is : Testing

---

For Catergory :    time shall time

The title is : I have made it

---

For Catergory :    Circular

The title is : I have made it

---

For Catergory :    Circular

The title is : Me

---

For Catergory :    A good Begining

The title is : A Remarkable move

---

For Catergory :    time shall time

The title is :

---

For Catergory :    A good Begining

The title is : A welcome note

---

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much impossible to figure out what your code does, because it doesn't actually work. Apparently, it parses some data, but you don't tell us how it parses that data, what that data is and you don't provide any example data. Also, it seems that it depends on some libraries, but you don't tell us what those libraries are. The local variable `docs` which seems to be pretty much the most important thing in your code, is not defined. And instead of showing us what the output is that you want, you only show us what the output is that you *don't* want.

Anyway, as far as I have been able to figure out, this seems to be what you want:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri.XML(open('http://googleblog.blogspot.com/atom.xml'))

puts doc.css('entry').reduce(Hash.new {|hsh, key| hsh[key] = [] }) {|cats, entry|
  cats.tap {|cats|
    entry.css('category').each {|cat|
      cats[cat['term']] << entry.css('title').text
    }
  }
}.reduce('') {|s, (cat, titles)|
  s.tap {|s|
    s << "  For Category :    #{cat}\n"
    s << titles.reduce('') {|s, title|
      s.tap {|s|
        s << "The title is : #{title}\n"
      }
    }
    s << "---------------------------------------------------\n"
  }
}
```

It would also have been nice to know that you are actually processing an Atom feed. If I had known that beforehand, I wouldn't have had to write all that parsing logic myself, I could have just used an Atom parsing library.

Comment: Sometimes, frustration can make one do what is not obtainable. I am sorry I committed such blunder in my question but thank God you were able to realize what I was talking about. The 'docs' is the body of a response I got from a net/http call. I wanted to match the elements of the root of the REXML document 'doc' which comprises Post_Id, Category, Content of the post, Author, Date published. so the above code is culled from my main code.